# Errors when trying to prepare testing with Ruby on Rails that uses a SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2008, activerecord

What do I need to do to be able to run tests with a SQL Server 2008 database server using the gem `activerecord-sqlserver-adapter`?

I am able to connect to the development database just fine using a 32bit ODBC connection through dev settings in database.yml:

```
#SQL Server
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: <odbc_name>
  username: <db_user>
  password: <db_password>
  host: <sql host>
```

I have started to setup some testing but run into an error when running:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Here is the error:

```
rake aborted!
ODBC::Error: 37000 (3708) [Microsoft][SQL Native Client][SQL Server]Cannot drop 
the database 'master' because it is a system database.: DROP DATABASE [master]

Tasks: TOP => db:test:load => db:test:purge
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This error doesn't make sense to me.  Why is it trying to drop the master db?

My test setup in database.yml is exactly the same as my dev above except it points to a different odbc which points to a different database.

**EDIT**

I have noticed that when I run `rake db:test:prepare` the first step must be to delete the test database.  So it knows what database it is supposed to use at first.

Why does it then try to delete the master?

Is this because when sql doesn't find the default database it gives the user master by default and `rake db:test:prepare` cannot create the users default db so it loops back to the beginning and tries to drop again?

Comment: it sounds like it is trying to drop and recreate the application database. For some reason it thinks that should be the database named "master". Check your target connection information and the dsn again and make sure that there are no unwanted characters in there. master is the default database for most logins. So it might try to use that if it can't find one in the configuration.

Comment: The error does lead you to believe that the user's default db is master but I double checked this user's default and it is the test database.  I also rewrote the test connection in ruby and made sure that all the information was correct.  I am still getting the error. Bug?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by specifying the name of the database in the test configuration:

```
# config/database.yml
...
test:
    adapter: sqlserver
    mode: odbc
    dsn: <odbc_name>
    database: <database_name>
    username: <db_user>
    password: <db_password>
...
```

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work for me. See edit above. Thank you!